# How can I get the exact solution of an ODE by using Scilab?

Tags: ode, scilab

I would like to get the exact solution of an ODE by using Scilab, I know how to do this in MATLAB and I am going to attach my MATLAB code, how can I convert this code to SCILAB?

````
clear all;
syms y(t)
function1=diff(y,t)==-0.5*(3+y)*cos(t)
Ic=y(0)==-4;
sol=dsolve(function1,Ic) ```
````

Comment: Scilab is no CAS, and also in Matlab the symbolic capabilities were a late addition. Both were primarily designed as interfaces to numerical algorithms, especially those involving large-scale linear algebra.

Comment: You mean this option is not available in Scilabe yet?

Comment: It would require to patch on a small CAS with big integers, rational numbers, algebraic extensions, expression trees and then on top of that implement the logic to classify ODE types, detect chains of transformations, simplify them back,... and all that for the small subset of textbook examples that are actually symbolically solvable. It would be a huge investment, much larger than just switching the ODE solvers to the sundials package. Another way would be to add a wrapper to an existing CAS like octave does, but still, is that the purpose of scilab?

Comment: I know this is not the purpose of scilab, just I am looking for finding the exact solution using scilab if this is possible. Thank you very much @Lutz Lehmann

Answer (score 1):

The Scimax module was implemented for Scilab 5.3 and 5.4 as an interface to work with Maxima within Scilab:
http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/scimax/
It required the external *overload* module: https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/Overload_Toolbox

It worked only on Linux. It has never been ported to Windows, nor to next Scilab versions.
But you can work directly with Maxima, that's also free, without using Scilab: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/

If you are using Scilab on Linux, you may still download Scilab 5.4 and give Scimax a try: https://www.scilab.org/download/previous-versions